# Asterisk AGI - Originate a call using php agi

Tags: asterisk, phone-call, agi

Is anybody knows , how we can Originate an external number call using PHP AGI script ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have got two possible options.  One is use the "Originate" command.  See http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Example:+Originate for an example.

The other one, which is what I favor in my solutions, since it does not require AMI, is using spooled call files.  See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Call+Files for how to do them.  The trick, and I cannot stress it enough, is to create the spool file in /tmp and then "move" the file into the ../spool/asterisk/outgoing directory.

If you assign a unique channel variable key/value to the spooled call, you can then pick it up with your dial plan and route the call appropriately.

Comment: asterisk -rx "channel originate SIP/<number>@test extension <extension>@<channel>"')

Comment: Even works with local channels: `channel originate local/exten1@context extension exten2@context`