# Asterisk:- How to achieve Autodialling in Asterisk box in context with java

Tags: java, data-structures, sip, voip, asterisk

I have a web app, which connects user to asterisk box via SIP and allow user to call any mobile or landlines  number, Now I want to make it automatic, in current scenario User have to manually click on a html button called Dial to dial a number, 
Now what I want to achieve is "as soon as user logged in, Asterisk will automatically call 3 nos from the campaign list which is allocated to the user and gives the user call only when the client connected to it. That means caller will be given the call only when receiver receives it.

Any configuration or  java code will help, even any algorithm will help also, i know my English is poor so, sorry for any mistakes, I hope people will understand what I am trying to achieve from the above para.

Comment: A similar question was asked in December.  See answer at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089687/asterisk-agi-originate-a-call-using-php-agi/14104023#14104023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I higly recomend you use dialler code. becuase there are much more issues you never thought about.

http://www.vicidial.org

or other.

If you still think you are qualified enought to write your own code, you can read this page:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

Comment: Thanks for the second link, It helped me