# How to make asterisk dial a POTS number triggered by notification?

Tags: automation, sip, voip, asterisk, pbx

I'm setting up some higher end security systems for a client. I'm using blue iris (his request) which has alot of great options for alerting you via cell phone or POTS telephone call. Unfortunately the building is 100% VoIP with no POTS and the camera server is in that building. I want it to ring a house number via a Automated VOIP call when an event is triggered in blue Iris then play a pre-recorded message.

We have a couple of Asterisk/Elastix PBXes in the company. I'm not sure how to proceeded:

1. Blus iris event triggered, it sends message/request/alert to a extension on the PBX
2. PBX makes the automated call to the group of numbers whenever that extension is dialed/contacted/triggered/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use an external script file (PHP, Ruby, BASH) to generate your call request on the PBX.  See my answer at [
[Asterisk AGI - Originate a call using php agi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089687/asterisk-agi-originate-a-call-using-php-agi/14104023#14104023) 
] for more details.  However, what you're doing is entirely possible, as I do it myself for a couple of different solution sets.

Essentially, and most easily, you'd generate a call file via script and within it ensure you have a couple of channel variables set that are keys for specific routing.  When the call connects at the far end, the near end goes into a dialplan on the ASTPBX where exactly what message is played, after-message behaviour, etc, is managed by the channel variables you've set.